# several statements in lambda

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have the following statement

```
var evarage = productionreportentry
              .Sum(productionReportEntry => productionReportEntry.Cycletime);
```

I would like to add some logging inside the `Sum`  lambda. Is this possible?

Comment: I  am sorry but i do not understand your question. Could you clarify it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _inside_ the lambda. What is it that you want to log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, do something like:

```
var evarage = productionreportentry.Sum(productionReportEntry => 
{ 
   Trace.Writeline(productionReportEntry.Cycletime);
   return productionReportEntry.Cycletime;
});
```

Basically you add the curly brackets, and you need to explicitly return the value that the lambda is operating on, in this case the Cycletime which is used as part of the sum.

Comment: Note that this will only work with LINQ to Objects - anything requiring an expression tree instead of a delegate will fail here, as statement lambdas can't be converted to expression trees.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I've never used expression trees (not even 100% sure what they are) as I only get to work in .NET 2.0. But thanks for the comment Jon :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: It's also nice to beat you to an answer for a change! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you really want but you can have multiple statements like this

```
        var evarage = productionreportentry.Sum(productionReportEntry =>
            {
                CreateLog();
                return productionReportEntry.Cycletime;
            });
```